# C fopen call with variable name?

Tags: c, file-io

Is there ever a circumstance where the following would work? (I'm trying to pull the value of a variable and create a file based off the text stored in the array.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = "a"; 
    FILE *out;
    out = fopen( "%s.txt", a, "w" );
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe `char a[] = "a";`

Comment: Making assumptions FTW!

Comment: +1 (offsetting downvote). While this question may not reflect years of experience developing C applications, it looks like a legitimate question nevertheless.

Comment: It will work when there is a file `%s.txt` and the first byte of the pointer to where the `"a"` literal is stored is `'r'`, `'w'` or something similiar

Comment: There is no environment to allow this function with a different parameter list with the same name at the same time in the C language can not be defined.

Answer (score 15):

> Is there ever a circumstance where the following would work?

No.

---

***Do not make assumptions!*** Read the manual instead. It is really worth it.

```
char buf[0x100];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s.txt", random_string);
FILE *f = fopen(buf, "r");
```

Answer (score 8):

Not directly. But you could do it indirectly as follows (or anything similar to it)...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* a = "a"; 
    char* extension = ".txt";
    char fileSpec[strlen(a)+strlen(extension)+1];
    FILE *out;

    snprintf( fileSpec, sizeof( fileSpec ), "%s%s", a, extension );

    out = fopen( fileSpec, "w" );
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 Why? We've already ensured the buffer is bigger than the input. But... typically... yes

Comment: because one day you will forget to ensure. Better be safe twice than fail once!

Comment: @H2CO3 -- You don't know how anal I am. ~grin~ But, point taken.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's an element that presents itself in C, generally. "One day you'll forget to check for possible integer overflows", yet how many people do you see making those checks?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Very few, unfortunately, and that's why I'm continuously trying to suggest and educate Stack Overflowers (literally) to do so.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's a shame I don't see so much emphasis on *checking the return value* (of fgets, which seems to be your band-aid for `scanf` code that's broken for the same reason).

Comment: @undefined_behavior -- Actually... that would break wouldn't it... because snprintf() returns the size written **not** including the null terminator. So... you should have a `+1` on there shouldn't you? `char file_spec[snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%s, a, extension)+1];` -- that said, that approach makes me inherently uncomfortable.

Comment: @KScottPiel Indeed. I seem to have trouble with return values, too ;). Comment deleted to prevent misinformation spreading.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour You can perhaps read the reasoning behind my objection against `scanf()` at one of those questions :)

Comment: @H2CO3 -- yeah yeah yeah ~grin~

Comment: @H2CO3 ... and you can read KScottPiels behind his objection against `snprintf`, in this particular scenario. I think his is more reasonable.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I did... seen my reaction? "because one day you will forget to ensure. Better be safe twice than fail once!"

Comment: @H2CO3 That statement is as invalid as "H2CO3 will *always* forget to check the return value of `fgets`".

Comment: Don't make me break out my spidy powers and separate you two. ~grin~

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a char variable with a string literal. You should change your code to this:

```
char a[] = "a";
```

Another problem is that `fopen` function gets only 2 arguments, but you're passing three.

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work. You need an intermediate step using something like `sprintf()` to compose the string you want to pass to fopen().

Answer (score 1):

You need to read more about [fopen()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/):

> FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode );
>
> Open file
>
> Opens the file whose name is specified in the parameter filename and associates it with a 
>   stream that can be identified in future operations by the FILE pointer returned.

And here after how to fix your code

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

char a = 'a';
char filename[64];

FILE *out;
sprintf(filename, "%c.txt", a)

out = fopen( filename, "w");

fclose(out);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd have to sprintf() to a string beforehand and then call fopen(name,mode) as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread is closed but @soon's comment suggested me a way to do it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

    void main()
    {
      FILE *fs;
      char c[]="Dayum.csv";
      fs = fopen( ("%s", c),"a");
      if (fs == NULL)
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
          for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
            fprintf(fs, "%lf,%lf\n",i,j);
    fclose(fs);
    }
```

Since fopen works with 2 arguments, we can disguise it as a single argument-

```
fs = fopen( ("%s", c), "a" )
```

However, in case you decide to add file extension as in

```
char c[]="Dayum";
fs = fopen( ("%s.csv",c), "a")
```

it doesn't work. The system creates a file called "Dayum" which is processed as normal text file, and not csv format.

A note- if you can store values of extensions in one file and values of filenames in another, then join them to write a filename.extension array, that'd serve the purpose too.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I did:

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char fileName = "a"; 
    FILE *out;

    char fileToOpen[strlen(fileName) + 5]; 
    // strlen(fileName)+5 because it's the length of the file + length of ".txt" + char null

    strcpy(fileToOpen, fileName); 
    // Copying the file name to the variable that will open the file

    strcat(fileToOpen, ".txt"); 
    // appending the extension of the file

    out = fopen( fileToOpen, "w" ); 
    // opening the file with a variable name

    if(out == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(out);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

NO, `fopen()` returns a `FILE*`

`FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);`

**+**

char a[]= "a";

Comment: "_NO, fopen() returns a FILE*_" - yes, it does. But problem is not with it.

Answer (score -2):

```
strcpy(a, ".txt");
fopen(a, "w");
```

might do what you are requesting.

Comment: This is not valid with variable `a` declared as it is in the OP's code. Moreover, it would take much more than a change to that declaration to get an approach similar to this to do what the OP says they intend to do.